# Find value having leading and trailing space in DB table column - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a record which has value with leading and space in a column.

eg: column value is `'  D0019 '`

I want to pass this particular column in where clause.

```
select * from my_table where my_column='D0019';
```

Since the value has space, it doesn't detect from the where clause.

How can I select the record even it has leading and trailing spaces in the value?

My DB is `ORACLE`

========================================

UPDATE :

I get value only when I try

```
select * from my_table where my_column like '%D0019%'
```

not even with `' %D0019% '`

=============================================

UPDATE 2 :

```
SELECT my_column  ,DUMP(my_column) FROM my_table  WHERE my_column like '%D0019';
```

output is

```
"   D0019"  Typ=1 Len=6: 9,68,48,48,49,57
```

Comment: Use `trim(my_column)` in your query.. This function removes leading and trailing spaces.

Comment: @San trim did not work for me. This is why I raised this question here. also I don't want to check the values with space or like condition. I want to find the exact value just removing spaces.

Comment: @user2771655 can you try this and paste the output in your question ? `SELECT my_column ,DUMP(my_column) FROM my_table WHERE my_column like '%D0019%';` I guess, it is tabspace or something else. Let's check the `ascii` value stored.

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar   Here is the output
" D0019" Typ=1 Len=6: 9,68,48,48,49,57

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's not the normal space you have to remove. It's `Horizontal Tab character` . (Ascii 9).

The below `regexp` would strip all the charcters from ASCII range `0-32` , which are associated with the white space symbols.

```
select * from my_table
 WHERE
     REGEXP_REPLACE(my_column,'['||chr(1)||'-'||chr(32)||']' ) = 'D0019';
```

[More on ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com)

Comment: it says *Cause:    The regular expression did not have balanced brackets.

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
from my_table
where trim(my_column) = 'D0019';
```

**Edit:**

Based on the output of the `dump()` function your values not just contain (leading) spaces but also a tab character. the `trim()` function will only remove space characters, but not other whitespace.

In order to get rid of any whitespace at the beginning you will need to use `regexp_replace()`

```
select *
from my_table
where regexp_replace(my_column,'^(\s)+','') = 'D0019'
```

If you need to get rid of leading **and** trailing whitespace, the regex needs to be expanded:

```
select *
from my_table
where regexp_replace(my_column,'^(\s)+|(\s)+$','') = 'D0019'
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3326a/1

Comment: I'm not sure what else to provide you. I Don't know how this value is stored in the DB. If so I have to find it through the project which is not in my scope. Pls help to find the issue here.

Answer (score 1):

Seems as simple as (if I get it):

```
select * from TAB where REGEXP_LIKE (COL,'\s*D0019')
```

returns values such ' D0019', 'D0019', '  D0019', '    D0019' ...etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this;

```
    select * from my_table where my_column like '%D0019';
```

Comment: I want to find exact value D0019

Answer (score 0):

you can also use this if you want only spaces at start for the select:

```
select * from my_table where my_column like '% %D0019';
```

or

```
select * from my_table where my_column like ' %D0019';
```

Comment: First query doesn't work but second one. Yet I don't want to use the '%'